# yup - validate nested object conditionally based on top field value

Tags: javascript, yup

the following piece of code works:

```
import yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  shouldValidate: yup.boolean(),
  objs: yup.array().when(["shouldValidate"], {
    is: (value) => value,
    then: () =>
      yup
        .array()
        .of(yup.object().shape({ name: yup.string().required().min(5) }))
  }),
});


await schema.validate({ shouldValidate: "Yes", objs: [{ name: '123' }] });
```

However, when I try to do it in a more clean way the validation does not happen:

```
import yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
 shouldValidate: yup.boolean(),
 objs: yup.array(
   yup.object({
     name: yup.string().when(["shouldValidate"], {
       is: (value) => value,
       then: (schema) => schema.required().min(5),
     }),
   })
 ),
});


await schema.validate({ shouldValidate: "Yes", objs: [{}] });
```

In other words - I check one of the 'upper' fields in my schema tree in order to decide whether to validate 'nested' fields. Is there a way to do it in yup?